# Merging multiple dataframe lines into aggregate lines

Tags: python, pandas

For the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': {0: "A", 1: "A", 2:"A", 3: "B"}, 
       'Spec1': {0: '1', 1: '3', 2:'5',
                3: '1'},
       'Spec2': {0: '2a', 1: np.nan, 2:np.nan,
                3: np.nan}       
              }, columns=['Name', 'Spec1', 'Spec2'])

  Name Spec1 Spec2
0    A     1    2a
1    A     3   NaN
2    A     5   NaN
3    B     1   NaN
```

I would like to aggregate the columns into:

```
  Name Spec
0    A    1,3,5,2a
1    B    1
```

Is there a more "pandas" way of doing this than just looping and keeping track of the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or using `melt`

```
df.melt('Name').groupby('Name').value.apply(lambda x:','.join(pd.Series(x).dropna())).reset_index().rename(columns={'value':'spec'})



Out[2226]: 
  Name      spec
0    A  1,3,5,2a
1    B         1
```

Answer (score 0):

Group rows by name, combine column values as a list, dropping `NaN`:

```
df = df.groupby('Name').agg(lambda x: list(x.dropna()))

          Spec1 Spec2
Name                 
A     [1, 3, 5]  [2a]
B           [1]    []
```

Now merge `Spec1` and `Spec2` lists. Bring `Name` back as a column. Name the new `Spec` column.

```
df = (df.Spec1 + df.Spec2).reset_index().rename(columns={0:"Spec"})

  Name           Spec
0    A  [1, 3, 5, 2a]
1    B            [1]
```

Finally, convert `Spec` lists to string representations:

```
df.Spec = df.Spec.apply(','.join)

  Name      Spec
0    A  1,3,5,2a
1    B         1
```

Comment: kindly convert list to string ~ `df.Spec.apply(', '.join)`

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
In [966]: (df.set_index('Name').unstack()
             .dropna().reset_index()
             .groupby('Name')[0].apply(','.join))
Out[966]:
Name
A    1,3,5,2a
B           1
Name: 0, dtype: object
```